# How can I plug a Unity application into native Android and native iOS?

Tags: unity, android, ios, plugin

There are a lot of questions about running native Android and iOS code in Unity.  I am trying to run Unity inside of native Android and native iOS apps.

My problem is that I have two native apps, and I don't want to write code twice when I add a feature.

I currently have two native apps - one in Android and one in iOS.  I am trying to write code once, and add it to both.  Can I write a Unity program, and put that into my native apps?

I am thinking something along the lines of writing a Unity Android app, building it as an Activity instead of an APK, and launching that Activity from the native android app.  Then also the equivalent in iOS, whatever that may be.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to do what you are describing.

Comment: @Almo I most certainly do not.  It sounds miserable.  Do you have a better alternative?

Comment: Write one Unity application, deploy to many devices. Don't worry about "native". That's just my opinion; I'm all about pragmatic development. I wrote Cognizer with Unity, and it's deployed on Android, iOS, Windows, OSX, and Linux. Only platform-specific code is Android back button.

Comment: @Almo I would very much prefer that.  But the native apps already exist, and cannot be rebuilt in Unity (for logistical reasons).

Comment: I'm not sure these OSs support running "an app within an app", so you might be stuck. We'll leave the question open and see if anyone else has an answer. :)

Comment: It looks like Unity has something in Beta for Android, but not for iOS:  https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-android-app-version-2.751712/

Comment: I believe this may help . I remember using unity in a native app several years ago and it just seemed easier to import the native stuff and use within unity but I have yet to see this new content [Unity2019.3](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/06/17/add-features-powered-by-unity-to-native-mobile-apps/)

Comment: Only times I needed to mess with Android specific code were when I required to initialize an intent (to open an external app) because Unity doesn't abstract that. And to put a updater service class that can continue running when player closes game (test app that isn't in store, to allow tester to check for updates the old way). Take a look at `AndroidJavaClass` in Unity docs. Do almost everything in Unity and try to maintain OS specific code to a minimum. Write simple classes as an Android library in Android Studio if you have to, and load them using `AndroidJavaClass` in Unity (...)

Comment: (...) Also see: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html I guess there are an equivalent for iOS and WindowsPhone.